# How do I expose the immutable messages of an Akka Actor to non-actor world?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I'm struggling with the interaction of actor systems and non-actor code. Section 3.2.1 of the [Akka Java documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/typed-actors.html#When_to_use_Typed_Actors) describes using TypedActors to perform bridging between an Actor system and the outside non-actor world.

> Typed actors are nice for bridging between actor systems (the “inside”) and non-actor code (the “outside”), because they allow you to write normal OO-looking code on the outside.

It then goes on to describe three different scenarios:

- One-way message send
- Request-reply message send
- Request-reply-with-future message send

But all of those scenarios are initiated from the non-actor world. What is the proper way for the actor system to call the non-actor code?

What I'm trying to do is expose the immutable payload of an actor message directly to the non-actor world. For example, actor A retains the immutable payload (say a map) of a message that it receives from actor B as a volatile instance variable, and then exposes that variable to the non-actor world for performance reasons (via a normal getter or a facade). That map is immutable, so its inherently thread-safe and thus does not require the overhead of routing messages, etc. Actor A is accessed by lots of non-actor threads and every once in a while, it receives an updated map from Actor B.

```
public class ActorAFacade extends UntypedActor implements Map<String, String> {
    private volatile Map<String, String> immutableMap = Collections.emptyMap();

    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
       return immutableMap.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Read Only!");
    }

    ... 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof Map) {            
            immutableMap = (Map<String, String>) message;
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid the overhead of creating and routing messages for each of the map methods (whether its done manually by an untyped actor or automatically by a typed actor).

Is this hybrid approach a viable solution (does it violate the spirit of actor systems)? Is there a better approach that Akka provides (i.e an event bus, call backs, etc)?

Comment: You might want to look at [Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/java/agents.html) or the [Futures and Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/java/index-futures.html) chapter in general for this.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for - "Reading an Agent's current value does not involve any message passing and happens immediately. So while updates to an Agent are asynchronous, reading the state of an Agent is synchronous." Thanks!

Comment: I guess I should post this as an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/java/agents.html) or the [Futures and Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/java/index-futures.html) chapter in general for this.

Comment: It's deprecated for new versions.

Comment: True. What's the alternative these days? I haven't kept an eye on Akka lately.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an alternative nowadays, as it doesn't work across a network.  It's been removed in 2.6, and no one has stepped forward to take up the offer of maintaining it as a contributed package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your asking by non-actor world, do you mean ask?

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("system");
ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(SomeActor.class), "someActor");

Timeout t = new Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(actor, "some message", 1000);
try {String response = (String) Await.result(future, t.duration());} catch(Exception e){}
```

So basically you send message being "some message" to the SomeActor actor, then in it's onReceive method you need to have

```
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception
    {
            if (msg instancof String)
            {
                getSender().tell("here is the response");
            }
    }
```

so if you do a System.out.println(response) it will print "here is the response"
But yeah could use agents as well as shown in the comments but they freak me out ( ;